# Polymorphism in an array of elements

Tags: arrays, fortran, function-pointers

Suppose I have defined a derived type (in Fortran 2003) named `geometry` and I extend it to two new derived types: `circle` and `triangle`. Each extended type has its own constructor, `NewCircle` and `NewTriangle` that returns a `circle` object and a `triangle` object respectively.

Then I would like to do this:

```
use appropriate_module
class(geometry), allocatable :: Geo(:)
allocate(Geo(2))
Geo(1) = NewCircle
Geo(2) = NewTriangle
```

Of course the last two lines are invalid in Fortran 2003 standard. 
I do not want to create an array of pointers encapsulated in a derived type to link object of different type because the objects need to be created before being linked in the array. In the above (hypothetical) case, the objects would be created and stored in the array immediately.

Any suggestion to do it, or is it a limitation of the language?

Comment: You know that the approach doesn't work and an approach that does, so I'm afraid I don't understand your question.  What is it that you want to achieve?  That is, discussion around "creation" is unclear.

Comment: Is it not acceptable to make an array of pointers in a derived type and point (or "link" ) each pointer to a pointer generated by a "new" routine (analogous to that in C++) that returns a pointer to a new object? Then there is formally no object generated beforehand.

Comment: This is how the language works. Every element in an array must have the same type. It is fundamental, especially, they must have the same storage size, but that is not the only reason. You know the solution by a creating an array of pointers, so I have no idea what you wan't to hear more.

Answer (score 2):

If you want value semantics, create an array of derived type with a polymorphic allocatable component.

```
use appropriate_module
type geometry_element
  class(geometry), allocatable :: item
end type geometry_element

type(geometry_element), allocatable :: geo(:)
geo = [ geometry_element(NewCircle()),  &
        geometry_element(NewTriangle()) ]
```

If a new `geometry` object was passed back to the calling scope using an allocatable argument (rather than via a function result), then the `MOVE_ALLOC` intrinsic provides an efficient way of moving the constructed value into an element of the array.

Comment: I am now trying the above code in various ways, but getting an error "Can't convert TYPE(NewCircle) to CLASS(geometry)" (with gfortran4.8). ifort14.0 also returns a similar error (even with -assume realloc_lhs). For this to work, is it necessary to overload geometry_element() with some custom function that allocates with "source=" keyword? (If so, the code ran for me.)

Comment: @roygvib Can you try with ifort 15?  I seem to recall I came across issues in older iforts with default constructors and allocatable components.

Comment: @francescalus Hmm.. I have no ifort15 at hand so cannot try...  I will install it if possible.

Comment: Defining a polymorphic allocatable component via a structure constructor requires a Fortran 2008 compiler (the behaviour is defined in terms of assignment to a polymorphic allocatable variable).  ifort is not yet such a compiler. For older Fortran standards you can either use `ALLOCATE(geo(nn)%item, SOURCE=NewXxxx())` **or** provide a defined assignment for the `geometry_element` type that takes `CLASS(geometry)` for the argument corresponding to the right hand side of `geo(nn) = NewXxxx()` as workarounds.