# Pointing to a object's type variable - Fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran

As I understand, a user-derived type's definition can't contain `target` attributes. E.g., this isn't allowed:

```
type TestType
    integer, target :: t
end type
```

However, it's fine for them to be a pointer:

```
type TestType2
    integer, pointer :: p
end type
```

My question is, then, how can one use a pointer to point at an object's type variable? For example, if I wanted an object of `type(TestType2)` to have its `p` variable point to an object of `type(TestType)`'s `t` variable, how would I go about this? For example:

```
type(TestType) :: tt
type(TestType2) :: tt2
tt%t = 1
tt%p => tt%t
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite follow your question.  You seem to know that the `t` component cannot be a target, but you still want to be able to have a pointer have it as a target?  That's not possible.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't too clear, I'm basically asking if there's any workaround for this that would ostensibly achieve the same/similar thing? I'm also curious as to why this constraint exists - I'm sure there must be a good reason for it.

Comment: How about attaching the target attribute to tt such that "type(TestType), target :: tt"? Then, I think all the components of tt assume the target attribute also (right?), and so they can be pointed by other pointers.

Answer (score 3):

There would be very little sense in

```
type TestType
    integer, target :: t
end type
```

because values of `type(TestType)` may easily come up in contexts where
they cannot be a target of a pointer.

As @roygvib comments, you have to give the `target` attribute to the whole object variable:

```
type(TestType), target :: tt
```

then you can make pointers to any of its components.

I could imagine that one could allow giving the target attribute to allocatable structure components in the type declaration, but it is not allowed. Certainly that would not make good sense for regular components.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @roygvib and @Vladimir F, I hadn't realised that giving the whole object variable the `target` attribute would allow me to point to any of its components. That worked perfectly.

For posterity, as my use case was a little more complex than the example above, I thought I'd post a more representative example of what I was trying to achieve. I was creating a grid system containing `GridCell`s and `River`s, each GridCell having an array of Rivers, and each River also having an array of Rivers that flow into in (`inflows`) - these inflows would be Rivers that have been previously created and stored in the GridCell's array of rivers. I wanted to use pointers so that the inflows could just point to the corresponding river in a particular GridCell's rivers array.

The added complication is that `River` itself is an abstract type, extended by different `SubRiver`s (SubRiver1 and SubRiver2 in the example below). I wanted the arrays of rivers and inflows to be of `class(River)` (i.e., polymorphic) and the only way to achieve that without Fortran complaining about polymorphic arrays was to create another user-derived type `RiverElement` with a polymorphic `class(River), allocatable :: item` property to store the river (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106539/polymorphism-in-an-array-of-elements)).

Finally, because I couldn't set the `inflows` array such that each item was a pointer (setting `inflows(:)` as a pointer makes a pointer array, not an array of pointer), I had to create another user-derived type specifically for storing pointers to Rivers.

Here's the module with all the type definitions:

```
module TestModule
    implicit none

    type :: RiverPointer
        class(River), pointer :: item => null()
    end type

    type, abstract :: River
        type(RiverPointer), allocatable :: inflows(:)
        integer :: id
    end type

    type :: RiverElement
        class(River), allocatable :: item
    end type

    type :: GridCell
        type(RiverElement), allocatable :: rivers(:)
    end type

    type, extends(River) :: SubRiver1
    end type

    type, extends(River) :: SubRiver2
    end type

end module
```

And here's a test program showing that it works:

```
program main
    use TestModule
    implicit none

    type(GridCell), target :: gc
    type(SubRiver1) :: sr1
    type(SubRiver2) :: sr2
    type(SubRiver1) :: sr3

    sr1%id = 1
    sr2%id = 2
    sr3%id = 3
    allocate(gc%rivers(3))
    allocate(gc%rivers(1)%item, source=sr1)
    allocate(gc%rivers(2)%item, source=sr2)
    allocate(gc%rivers(3)%item, source=sr3)

    allocate(sr3%inflows(2))
    sr3%inflows(1)%item => gc%rivers(1)%item
    sr3%inflows(2)%item => gc%rivers(2)%item

    write(*,*) sr3%inflows(1)%item%id           ! 1
    write(*,*) sr3%inflows(2)%item%id           ! 2
    gc%rivers(1)%item%id = 100
    write(*,*) sr3%inflows(1)%item%id           ! 100
end program
```

Thanks all!